# Type of Transformer in SMPS

Tags: transformer

Can anyone tell me the type and model of transformer (T1) in the following circuit diagram.
[image]

Comment: Since it's a flyback converter T1 is most correctly named *inductor* though

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's not an iron transformer. Instead, it's a high-frequency transformer with [E16 core](https://en.tdk.eu/inf/80/db/fer_13/e_16_8_5.pdf) (probably 3F3 or N27 material) and [a suitable coil former](http://tr.farnell.com/epcos/b66308b1108t001/coil-former-e-16-1-section-8-pin/dp/2355074).

Circuit scheme does not provide number of turns, so you need to check the datasheet or an application note or calculate by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It can be either ICE Components TP07160, or Precision Inc. 019-6119-00R.

It is an EE16 gapped core [NC-2H](http://www.nicera.co.jp/pro/ff/pdf/FP-NC-2H.pdf) or equivalent material, and the transformer is made to specifications of the chip maker.

Answer (score 0):

See this from [Premier Magnetics](http://www.premiermag.com/pdf/link.pdf): -

[image]

I've highlighted a couple that look promising.

They make quite a few transformers for Power Integrations range of chips so click on the link in the left hand column to open the transformer spec. If it's not exactly the same as implied in your question, at least you have a fully supported design using a different core.